# jq, locale and strptime: how to use properly

Tags: json, locale, jq

I have this input

```
{"text": "05 april 2017"}
```

If I run `echo '{"text": "05 april 2017"}' | jq '.text|strptime("%d %B %Y")'` I have the right result.

If I set temporary my locale in italian with `export LC_ALL=it_IT.utf8` and apply `.text|strptime("%d %B %Y")` to

```
{"text": "05 aprile 2017"}
```

I have `date "05 aprile 2017" does not match format "%d %B %Y"`.

Ho to manage date localization settings with jq to recognize months local name?

Thank you

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.c#L1301 I'd say it should "just work".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is a bug open for this issue. https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1740

Currently (in v1.6), localization is not supported for date functionality.